# Refine - unable to create React project using CLI refine-app@latest

Tags: reactjs, react-refine

Am using [Refine framework](https://refine.dev/docs/tutorial/getting-started/headless/create-project/#launch-the-refine-cli-setup) to create an app, running the command below -

```
npm create refine-app@latest
```

It fails everytime, with the error in `superplate-cli`

> × Could not retrieve source repository. Could not retrieve source
> repository. Source can be a remote git repository or a local path.
>
> You provided: undefined
>
> Run superplate-cli --help to see all options.

I reckon `refine-app` runs the `superplate-cli` under the hood, so tried running `npx superplate-cli` directly and get the exact same error.

How do I thus create a refine app using the CLI?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the problem with no luck. I'm using node `v18.16.0` and npm `9.5.1` and it works fine for me. It might be about your nodejs and/or npm versions. And also make sure you aren't passing any extra parameter to this command accidently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is due to download issues related to `superplate-cli`.

Could be the same as here: https://github.com/refinedev/refine/issues/3238#issuecomment-1353062756

I also faced the problem multiple times. But it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

try to install superplate-cli frpm your terminal with "npm i superplate-cli" then run "npx superplate-cli -p refine your-project-name"